# Missing @CreationTimestamp and @UpdateTimestamp after generating persistence mapping by database schema

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, intellij-idea, hibernate-mapping

This link [How to generate persistence mapping by database schema during build of the project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62372612/how-to-generate-persistence-mapping-by-database-schema-during-build-of-the-proje) described a way to generate persistence mapping by database schema - automatically creating entity classes for Hibernate.

I've followed the instructions and proceed this with settings:
[image]
The result of this was different from expected.
The table was created in MySQL with this script:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS orders(
  order_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  updated_at  TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

After mapping, it didn't add the @CreationTimestamp and @UpdateTimestamp annotations to fields created_at  and updated_at. How to make it to be able to create these annotations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using scripted extensions to Generate a Java POJO entity class for the selected table in **Project tool window**. In the dialog that opens, specify the directory in which the .java class file should be generated. Please see attached screenshot. You can customize the script to generate any text. See also [these examples](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-97873#focus=streamItem-27-2901987.0-0) and [Generate simple classes from database objects in DataGrip](https://blog.jetbrains.com/datagrip/2018/02/13/generate-pojos/) blog post.

[image]

Comment: May I ask, is it possible to add this during build of the project?

Comment: No, this action (`Generate POJOs`) can not be configured to run automatically on e.g. a project build. Please feel free to file a request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA

Comment: May I ask, where to get from the code for "generate persistence mapping by database schema"

Answer (score 0):

IntelliJ IDEA won't add @CreationTimestamp and @UpdateTimestamp annotations on fields, you have to manually add those annotations on fields.

Comment: My project changes the database structure every day since it's a new project. I'm not allowed to keep my classes inside the repository and they have to be auto-generated. I need to find a way to automatically generate classes by the database with these annotations. I need to launch this generation creation  during the build of the project

Comment: Always autogenerated  ? project structure changed then you have to be updated but always generate is not a good idea.

Comment: I was given a task to provide it. I can't keep my classes in the repository. I use Flyway to generate a database with SQL script and based on this SQL script or the database I have to autogenerate classes. I'm not allowed to spend time changing classes each time database changes